# How to display Power View Reports inside asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, powerview

We have a powerview report (.rdlx) created in sharepoint and is accessible from sharepoint. My objective is to create a .aspx page and call the powerview report in it. I can do it using iframe but thats not what I want. In iframe, the menu ribbon and the grey background of the sharepoint is also visible.

Is there any other way to call a powerview report using server name and report path as in report viewer control for ssrs reports ? I want to show just the report.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you click on rdlx report in Sharepoint, it opens Power View in presentation mode. You can grab that URL and use it. For another report you'll need to pass rdlx ID instead of the name. Or you can view html source and see how Power View is embedded into the page.

Comment: You can also manage how the view behaves using URL parameters, much like in SSRS. See here for details: http://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/url-actions-with-reporting-services-power-view-rtm/